# Bootgrid with pagination not posting all rows

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, pagination

I have a c# .net web app and when the paginator is enabled, it removes the hidden table rows from the DOM. When submitting the form, I only have the current table page rows being posted. I need all the table rows to be posted.

Is there an option or a way to have all the table rows posted not just the current page from the paginator?

Answer (score 0):

here is a work-around for me:

init bootgrid with `rowCount: -1`, make sure there is no pagination, then collecting all the table cells using jQuery.